# How to get Dynamic values from BuildRowSet string

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the BuildRowset string to split the string and store the string in the variable, but i am taking the value manually from Data Extension attribute called Subscriber field.  In that field string is stored separated by commas, I don't know how many strings are stored in that attribute.

I have tried:

```
%%[

VAR @Text ,@Split1, @Split2, @Split3

SET @rowset = LookupRows("raviDE","Email", "somemail@gmail.com")
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)
set @act=Field(@row,"subscrption")
SET @Rows = BuildRowSetFromString(@act, ",")

SET @Split1 = Field(Row(@Rows, 1), 1)
SET @Split2 = Field(Row(@Rows, 2), 1)
SET @Split3 = Field(Row(@Rows, 3), 1)

if @Split1=="bed"  then
    SET @acts= "checked" 
endif
if @Split2=="clock"  then
    SET @acts1= "checked" 
endif
if @Split3=="phone"  then
    SET @acts2= "checked" 
endif
if  @Split1==False then
    SET @act="" 
endif
if  @Split2==False then
    SET @act="" 
endif

]%%
%%=v(@Split1)=%%</br>
%%=v(@Split2)=%%</br>
%%=v(@Split3)=%%</br>


<form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://pages.S7.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=38dfbe491fab00ea0ad4b925273e8608d40bab6a35b96d3428a16f6a0f519dc7">
Email: <input type="text" name="test4" value="%%=Field(@row, "Email")=%%" /></br>
Checkbox:<input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="bed"  %%=v(@acts)=%%/> A Bed
<input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="clock" %%=v(@acts1)=%%/> A Clock
<input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="phone" %%=v(@acts2)=%%/> A phone

<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form
```

>

Error Message:

> An unexpected error has occurred! Error Message:  Invalid index
>   (parameter 2) passed to Row function. Index must be less than or equal
>   to the row count. Index Value: 2 Row Count: 1 Function: Row(@Rows, 2) 
>   Description:  An unexpected error occurred during the execution of the
>   page.

**How to rectify the error using Amp script?**

Now I am facing another issue:

```
%%[/* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none"> */
VAR @email, @Split1, @Split2, @Split3, @acts, @acts2, @acts3
SET @rowset = LookupRows("raviDE","Email", "aomemail@gmail.com")
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)
set @email = "aomemail@gmail.com"
if rowcount(@rowset) > 0 then 
  set @email = Field(@row, "Email")
endif
set @act = Field(@row,"subscrption")
SET @Rows = BuildRowSetFromString(@act, ",")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 
output(concat("<br>@rowCount: ", @rowCount))
set @split1 = ""
set @split2 = ""
set @split3 = ""
set @acts = ""
set @acts2 = ""
set @acts3 = ""
if @rowCount > 0 then
  if @rowCount >= 1 then
    SET @Split1 = Field(Row(@Rows, 1), 1)
  endif 
  if @rowCount >= 2 then
    SET @Split2 = Field(Row(@Rows, 2), 1)
  endif 
  if @rowCount >= 3 then
    SET @Split3 = Field(Row(@Rows, 3), 1)
  endif 
  if @Split1 == "Seasonal travel information and trip ideas"  then
      SET @acts= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split1 == "Travel Deals-monthly"  then
      SET @acts1= "checked" 
  endif
if @Split1 == "Ski Deals Seasonal"  then
      SET@acts2 = "checked" 
  endif
 if @Split2 == "Seasonal travel information and trip ideas"  then
      SET @acts= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split2 == "Travel Deals-monthly"  then
      SET @acts1= "checked" 
  endif
if @Split2 == "Ski Deals Seasonal"  then
      SET @acts2= "checked" 
  endif
 if @Split3 == "Seasonal travel information and trip ideas"  then
      SET @acts= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split3 == "Travel Deals-monthly"  then
      SET @acts1= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split3 == "Ski Deals Seasonal"  then
      SET @acts2= "checked" 
  endif
endif
/*</div>*/
]%%
<br>%%=v(@Split1)=%%
<br>%%=v(@Split2)=%%
<br>%%=v(@Split3)=%%
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://pages.S7.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=38dfbe491fab00ea0ad4b925273e8608d40bab6a35b96d3428a16f6a0f519dc7">
<br>Email: <input type="text" name="test4" value="%%=v(@email)=%%" />
<br>Checkbox:<input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="Seasonal travel information and trip ideas"  %%=v(@acts)=%%/> Seasonal travel information and trip ideas
<br><input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="Travel Deals-monthly" %%=v(@acts1)=%%/> Travel Deals-monthly
<br><input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="Ski Deals Seasonal" %%=v(@acts2)=%%/> Ski Deals Seasonal
<br><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
Here I am using lot of If conditions in these lines:

if @Split1 == "Seasonal travel information and trip ideas"  then
      SET @acts= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split1 == "Travel Deals-monthly"  then
      SET @acts1= "checked" 
  endif
if @Split1 == "Ski Deals Seasonal"  then
      SET@acts2 = "checked" 
  endif
 if @Split2 == "Seasonal travel information and trip ideas"  then
      SET @acts= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split2 == "Travel Deals-monthly"  then
      SET @acts1= "checked" 
  endif
if @Split2 == "Ski Deals Seasonal"  then
      SET @acts2= "checked" 
  endif
 if @Split3 == "Seasonal travel information and trip ideas"  then
      SET @acts= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split3 == "Travel Deals-monthly"  then
      SET @acts1= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split3 == "Ski Deals Seasonal"  then
      SET @acts2= "checked" 
  endif
```

Is it possible to minimize the If conditions using AMPScript code? can anyone please help me?

Comment: @Adam spriggs please help me , for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the rowcount before you start pulling field values from the results -- not just for the split fields, but also for the email lookup:

```
%%[

VAR @email, @Split1, @Split2, @Split3, @acts, @acts2, @acts3

SET @rowset = LookupRows("raviDE","Email", "somemail@gmail.com")
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)

set @email = ""
if rowcount(@row) > 0 then 
  set @email = Field(@row, "Email")
endif

set @act = Field(@row,"subscrption")
SET @Rows = BuildRowSetFromString(@act, ",")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

output(concat("<br>@rowCount: ", @rowCount))

set @split1 = ""
set @split2 = ""
set @split3 = ""
set @acts = ""
set @acts2 = ""
set @acts3 = ""

if @rowCount > 0 then

  if @rowCount >= 1 then
    SET @Split1 = Field(Row(@Rows, 1), 1)
  endif 

  if @rowCount >= 2 then
    SET @Split2 = Field(Row(@Rows, 2), 1)
  endif 

  if @rowCount >= 3 then
    SET @Split3 = Field(Row(@Rows, 3), 1)
  endif 

  if @Split1 == "bed"  then
      SET @acts= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split2 == "clock"  then
      SET @acts1= "checked" 
  endif
  if @Split3 == "phone"  then
      SET @acts2= "checked" 
  endif

endif


]%%
<br>%%=v(@Split1)=%%
<br>%%=v(@Split2)=%%
<br>%%=v(@Split3)=%%

<form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://pages.S7.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=38dfbe491fab00ea0ad4b925273e8608d40bab6a35b96d3428a16f6a0f519dc7">
<br>Email: <input type="text" name="test4" value="%%=v(@email)=%%" />
<br>Checkbox:<input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="bed"  %%=v(@acts)=%%/> A Bed
<br><input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="clock" %%=v(@acts1)=%%/> A Clock
<br><input type="checkbox" name="test5" value="phone" %%=v(@acts2)=%%/> A phone
<br><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @Learninguser You have been rude and abusive in your comments, so I removed them. Please refrain from comments like *please help*. Please do not beg users for votes either. The system auto-banned you based on your posting behavior, and voting your question up would not change that.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I have changed my question please help for this scenario

Comment: @AdamSpriggs can you please help me,minimse of If conditions what is the way